# Get all file names in folder to array and sort in alphabetically with string and number

Tags: vba

I have filenames in an folder that start with these:

```
W1
W2
W3
W10
W22
W34
```

When I put them into an array, and output them, it comes out like this:

```
W1 
W10 
W2 
W22 
W3 
W34
```

I want to sort it by the number and not like above output. I've tried bubble sort, but doesn't seem to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = listfiles(myPath)

 '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Need help here to sort the array.


End Sub
```

Here is my get files to array. Unless someone knows a better way to do it. Please help.

```
Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    listfiles = vaArray

End Function
```

Comment: You will need to parse the names to include two digit numbers.  So you will need to make `W1` into `W01` then sort by that.

Comment: so you're saying, I have to rename the files to include the "0" in front of the number? Would I need to open each file, parse the filename to include the "0" or is there a way to do it without having to open the file/save etc?

Comment: you can parse the resultant array instead, and parse the string from its name.  Sort then remove the `0` that was added.  But without adding the `0` it would be a lot more work as you will need to split the array by the length of the string and sort first the two character then the three then the four and so on then append each array to a larger.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your sort method to treat the name as [initial character]+[numeric part] and perform the value comparisons accordingly.

```vb
Sub tester()

    Dim arr, newArr

    arr = Array("W33 Horse", "W1 blah", "W2 another", _
                "W30 word", "W20 here", "W100 also")

    Debug.Print "Original:" & vbLf & Join(arr, vbLf)
    SortSpecial arr, "PartOfName"
    Debug.Print "Sorted:" & vbLf & Join(arr, vbLf)

End Sub

'Sorts an array using some specific formatting/translation defined in `func`
'  func is any function which takes one argument and returns a value to use
'  in the sort comparison
Sub SortSpecial(list, func As String)
    Dim First As Long, Last As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmp, arrComp()
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    'fill the "compare array...
    ReDim arrComp(First To Last)
    For i = First To Last
        arrComp(i) = Application.Run(func, list(i))
    Next i
    'now sort by comparing on `arrComp` not `list`
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If arrComp(i) > arrComp(j) Then
                tmp = arrComp(j)          'swap positions in the "comparison" array
                arrComp(j) = arrComp(i)
                arrComp(i) = tmp
                tmp = list(j)             '...and in the original array
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

'Reformat by taking the part before the first space, then from that
' the first character, then appending zero-padded numeric remainder
'  Eg. "W3" >> "W00000003",  "W11" >> "W00000011"
Function PartOfName(ByVal v)
    Dim firstPart
    firstPart = Split(v, " ")(0) 'before first space
    PartOfName = Left(firstPart, 1) & _
                Format(Right(firstPart, Len(firstPart) - 1), "00000000")
End Function
```

You may need to modify the `PartOfName` function depending on exactly what your filenames look like.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary from the filenames with the keys being the numeric part of the first part of the filename and the values being the filenames.

That dictionary can then be sorted by key and the sorted filenames returned.

```
Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)
Dim dicFiles As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim oFile As Variant
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFiles As Object
Dim ky As Variant

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    Set dicFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each oFile In oFiles
        ky = Val(Mid(Split(oFile.Name, " ")(0), 2))
        dicFiles.Add ky, oFile.Name
    Next

    Set dicFiles = SortDictionaryByKey(dicFiles)

    listfiles = dicFiles.items

End Function

Public Function SortDictionaryByKey(dict As Object) As Object
Dim arrKeys As Object
Dim dictSorted As Object
Dim key As Variant

    Set arrKeys = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each key In dict
        arrKeys.Add key
    Next key

    arrKeys.Sort

    Set dictSorted = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each key In arrKeys
        dictSorted.Add key, dict(key)
    Next key

    Set SortDictionaryByKey = dictSorted

End Function
```